# Android video streaming to windows azure

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-capture, azure-storage

I want to store **stream video to the *windows azure server from the android camera*** captured video*.How it possible?

In android i know the use of **parcelfiledescriptor** class.And i also created a application to stream video to the server.In that application server side controled by java socket programming.that fully successful..

But now i want the server side programming to do with the help of Windows Azure ???please help me.....thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

can you just upload the video as blob to Window Azure Blob Storage? More recently, Windows Azure Media Services has been shipped, which is specialized in supporting video.

Answer (score 0):

do not know about windows azure, but there is a way to stream to wowza servers:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde

Answer (score 0):

For applications using the Azure storage version 2009-04-14 and newer, you can request Azure to deliver partial content (HTTP 206 responses). You can simply upload the video file and then load it for streaming.

[This might be helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691967.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), although now it is rarely necessary to manage the HTTP 206 responses in such a detail, the SDK should do it for you.